# Best way to show attachments

Tags: modal, carousel, files

I've designed an HTML table where each row can contain attachments. Each row has a grey paper clip icon which, when clicked, opens a file selector. The user can then upload file(s) to S3.

After a successful upload, the grey paper clip icon then turns green. The user can click a newly displayed button that opens up a modal with a carousel in it. The carousel shows the uploaded files (pics, PDFs, etc.) with the the S3 urls.

This works, but I'm wondering: is it an optimal pattern for this flow? If not, what might be some good alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deconstructing the proposed interaction pattern, I would invite you to empathise for a moment with your users who suffer from one or multiple forms of [visual impairments.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_impairment) For instance, if I suffer from color blindess, how do I distinguish the two statuses?

When color is used as the only visual means of conveying information, not only violates one of the [core principles of the WCAG guidelines](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/#use-of-color), but can also lead to usability issues related to the [recognition rather than recall heuristic.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/)

My suggestion is to don't rely on color only to highlight the two statuses and do some [usability testing](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/usability-testing-101/) to identify the potential issues of your design hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use a button for that. You can display the paperclip icon + the name of the file after the user clicked that button and uploaded the file. This way you tell the user exactly what they need to do there.

Or you can use a drop field for multiple uploads. Something similar to this. [image]

Comment: But what about if there's multiple attachments per row? I don't think we want multiple paperclips

Comment: In this case, why not user a drag and drop area for uploading multiple files. Here is a good example: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1231641/screenshots/7193229/media/3eb65f8c711a7567ae7831499722e7b5.png

Answer (score 1):

Use two separate, *distinct*, symbols for upload vs. download. They could be related - e.g., "Up arrow with a file" and "Down arrow with a file" - or they could be unrelated - one of them using a paper clip. Mouseover (for platforms that support mouseover) should show the meaning of the icon.

If the number of downloadable files is **usually** very small - e.g., no more than 4 - then I would use a separate icon for each file until the limit is reached. Ideally the icons should be specific to the file type (PDF, Word, Excel, JPEG, etc.).

If the number of downloadable files varies a lot, or if the number is usually small but is exceeded on a particular record, use a download icon together with a numeric indicator. That could be just a number or it could be with a word or two - e.g., "5 files". Mouseover should show more information - at a minimum "5 files available for download" but ideally more, such as file names/types.